# Push a view controller upon local notification tap after app is quit

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I am developing an iOS app in which a background fetch is performed and if certain conditions are met, a local notification is posted.

What I want is when the user taps on the notification a view controller of type `UIViewController` should be pushed on the `DashboardViewController` which is of type `UINavigationController`.

I have implemented custom delegate for the `UNUserNotification` inside which I post a Notification whenever user taps on the notification. I have then added an observer for that notification in the DashboardViewController.

If the observer catches that notification it pushes the view controller onto the NavigationController.

This works fine as long as the app is running in the background/foreground. The moment I remove the app from the recent activity sheet and the tap on the notification, only the main view is loaded. The other view controller is not pushed onto this view controller.

Here is the code from `UNUserNotificationDelegate`:

```swift
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        switch response.actionIdentifier {
        case UNNotificationDefaultActionIdentifier:
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .didTapOnAttendanceNotification, object: nil)
            completionHandler()
        case UNNotificationDismissActionIdentifier:
            completionHandler()
        default:
            completionHandler()
            break
        }
    }
```

And here is the code that I am using in the viewWillAppear of my `DashboardViewController`:

```swift
// Override view will appear
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    // Add observer for notification tap
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(attendanceDidTap), name: .didTapOnAttendanceNotification, object: nil)

    // Add observer for biometry
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleReauth), name: .isReauthRequired, object: nil)
}
```

Please note that I am not using Storyboards for this App.

Regards

Comment: did you tried it ?

Answer (score 0):

here is one of the way you can achieve the notification tap handling.

1. observe the notification tap in the `appdelegate` callback
2. get the RootNavigationController object from `appdelegate`
3. create DashboardViewController instance
4. override the instance in the rootNavigationController `viewcontroller` stack
5. thats it.

In Appdelegate,

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

      guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate, let window = appDelegate.window, let rootNav = window.rootViewController as? RootNavigationController else {
          return
      }                
       // instantiate dashboardViewController
       // Call the override function from here with dashboardController                
       rootNav.overrideDefaultViewController(viewController: DashboardController)
}
```

In your RootNavigation controller add the overrideDefaultViewController function

```
class RootNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    override init(rootViewController: UIViewController) {
        super.init(rootViewController: rootViewController)
    }

    // Pass the dasboard view controller here
    func overrideDefaultViewController(viewController: UIViewController) {
        self.viewControllers = [viewController]
    }
}
```